# Routing granular messages from Amazon SNS to SQS with filtering

Tags: amazon-web-services, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I am trying to achieve a point in a system architecture on top of AWS infrastructure where a message is published from a data processor and sent to multiple subscribers (clients). This message would contain information that some - but not all - clients would want to receive.

**Very similar question** > [Routing messages from Amazon SNS to SQS with filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196890/routing-messages-from-amazon-sns-to-sqs-with-filtering)

So to do this message filtering I have turned to the message [FilterPolicy functionality provided by SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simplify-pubsub-messaging-with-amazon-sns-message-filtering/) using one topic. Currently the system is reaching a point in time that clients have more granular and specific filtering rules so now I am reaching the filtering limits of the AWS SNS.

See more about the SNS filter policy here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html (section “Filter policy constraints”)

One example of my limitation is the amount of filter values in a policy, on above link it states 150 values. Right now my subscribers would be interested in receiving messages with a specific attribute value. Although this one attribute could have several hundreds or thousands of different values. 
I can not also group this attributes since they represent a non-sequential identity.

I seek some guidance over on a architectural solution that would allow me to keep using AWS SNS. I am limited to use some of the AWS infrastructure services, so no RabbitMQ for me.